# Show who last committed to branches on a remote

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote, git-log

Our remote repo has a ton of branches (for features and fixes) that have sinced been merged back into the main development. In an effort to clean up the repo, we've asked people to delete branches that are no longer necessary.

Is there a git command to list remote branches and who was the last person to commit to them?

Comment: No, there's no command for this, but by coincidence, I just wrote a tiny script to do this yesterday: https://gist.github.com/meagar/efb61fbd91f0188be7ba Note there are tons of scripts to do this, and lots of them are probably better than mine.

Comment: As far as listing remote branches, you can use `git branch -r` or `git remote show origin`. See [this post](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/13/list-remote-branches.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this lists all branches for original, and then prints out the branch+Author Name/Email for them.

```
for br in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/origin/
do
   echo "${br}    $(git show -s --format=\"%an %ae\" ${br})"
done
```

I don't think that's what you want to start out with though.  You probably would be better off using

```
git branch --merged origin/master
```

Or something similar.  Which answer the question of "which branches don't point to unique history and can be deleted".

Comment: Thanks! I actually used: `git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname) %(refname)' refs/remotes/origin`, but I wouldn't have gotten that far without your help.

Comment: Whoops!  I completely forgot to look up the other ref format specifiers.  That makes it a lot simpler